# Why is ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED not triggering my receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing an Android App which should log changes to cell network connectivity. I already succeeded in implementing a `BroadcastReceiver` to log MCC/MNC changes (using `android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE`) but I just can't get `CarrierConfigManager.ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED` to trigger my receiver. What am I missing?

I know that `ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED` is a whitelisted broadcast which should still work. I tried different spelling combinations in the intent filter (`android.telephony.CarrierConfigManager.ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED`, `CarrierConfigManager.ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED`, `ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED`, etc.).

From AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="CarrierConfigChangedReceiver" android:exported="true"> <!-- CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED -->
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telephony.CarrierConfigManager.ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

(note: I moved the receiver registration for my `ServiceStateChangedReceiver` to the `MainActivity` onCreate method, which works just as well as it did in the `AndroidManifest.xml` where it was previously) - but the `CarrierConfigChangedReceiver` does not work.

From CarrierConfigChangedReceiver.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class CarrierConfigChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String msg = "BNA";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(msg, "Carrier Config change detected");
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW this is a GSM/LTE phone in Germany, not CDMA

Comment: I assume there must be CarrierConfigChanged events happening, because I work for a mobile network provider and am triggering a preferredprovider change over our network on a roaming cellphone, and I can see it switching networks as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out lots of other intent events, i.e. `android.intent.action.ACTION_SUBINFO_CONTENT_CHANGE` (which works for me) I finally concluded that there are actually no `ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED` events in my setup. Unfortunately I was unable to find an exact definition of what exactly triggers an `ACTION_CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED`.

So I guess the answer is: it would work if such an event ever happened.